# MariaDB configuration in Spring Boot for AWS Aurora - write query routing to reader instance

Tags: mysql, spring, mariadb, rds, amazon-aurora

I have an application running MariaDB using Aurora RDS MySQL as datasource.

In my `application.properties`, I have:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb:aurora://****.cluster***.rds.amazonaws.com:3306,****.cluster-ro***.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/db
```

Intermittently, I see this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: (conn=150057) The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I have read answers to other questions on SO and they talk about this happens due to DNS caching used by AWS among other reasons.

I also talked to AWS support team, and they advised to only use write endpoints if the application does both read/write operations. However, the reader endpoint is responsible for load-balancing, so that functionality will be lost and all the queries will hit the writer instance.

I also read this article in MariaDB docs: [Aurora configuration in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/failover-and-high-availability-with-mariadb-connector-j/#aurora-configuration)

> [...] recommended url string has to use only cluster endpoint.
>
> Driver will automatically discover master and slaves of this cluster from current cluster end-point during connection time. This permits adding new replicas to the cluster instance which will be discovered without changing driver configuration.

Do I need to provide only the writer cluster endpoint and MariaDB will take care of load balancing between writer and reader endpoints? Or do I need to provide both with additional configuration?

Comment: What were your findings? I'm trying to configure the same thing, and as per the documents I read, it appears that we don't need to explicitly provide reader endpoint in JDBC connection host description.